# Using devtools' github_install without force = TRUE

Tags: r, devtools

I use devtools and after I updated to R 3.3.1 I have this message every time I install something via Github.

```
Skipping install of 'PACKAGE' from a github remote, the SHA1 (123456) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
```

Anybody had this issue too?

Comment: It's not an "issue", it's the default behavior. `install_github()` eventually calls an internal function `install_remote()` which checks if the current installation of the package is from GitHub and if it matches the SHA1 hash of what's available from the master branch. It's preventing a needless update.

Comment: @hrbrmstr yes, you've got the point, but the weird part is that it happens with packages that were not installed not even as dependencies of others :S

Comment: #unlikely. Look at the code for those functions that make the `devtools` magic happen. They pull data from your package library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the Issue while trying to install the packages try with below command:

```
install_github("Stat", force=TRUE)
```

It will force and help you to install.

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: quite old post but thank !! at that moment a fresh install solved it

Answer (score 0):

try this:
library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot", force=TRUE)

it worked for me :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).